# Fix "task body with multiple statements" error in a parity checker using a task

Tags: verilog

I designed an odd parity checker using task (8-bit input, 9-bit output, 1 error signal). When designing with this code, an error of "task body with multiple statements requires systemverilog" occurs. I am wondering how to fix it.

I need to write an odd parity checker that uses task to detect the error signal

Below is the verilog code I wrote

```
module TaskChecker(data_in, parity_out, error);
input [7:0] data_in;
output [8:0] parity_out;
output reg error;

task automatic parity;
    input [7:0] data;
    output [8:0] dout;
    output error;

    begin
        dout = {~^data, data};
    end

    begin
        error = dout[0];
    end
endtask

always @ (*) begin
    parity(data_in, parity_out, error);
end
endmodule
```

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module tb_TaskChecker;
reg [7:0] data_in;
wire [8:0] parity_out;
reg error;

TaskChecker tb(.data_in(data_in), .parity_out(parity_out));

initial
    begin
        $dumpfile("test_TaskChecker_out.vcd");
        $dumpvars(-1, tb);
        $monitor("b", parity_out, error);
    end

initial
    begin
        data_in = 8'b00000000;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00000001;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00000010;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00000011;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00000100;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00000101;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00000110;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00000111;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b00001000;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b10100011;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b11010010;
    #100;
        data_in = 8'b11111111;
    #100;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

If a task contains multiple statements, they must be contained within a `begin`-`end` block in Verilog. This rule was removed for SystemVerilog. So,

```
task automatic parity;
    input [7:0] data;
    output [8:0] dout;
    output error;

    begin

        begin
            dout = {~^data, data};
        end

        begin
            error = dout[0];
        end

    end
endtask
```

Or, more sensibly:

```
task automatic parity;
    input [7:0] data;
    output [8:0] dout;
    output error;
    begin
        dout = {~^data, data};
        error = dout[8];// MSB gives error bit
     end
endtask
```